# Update order status with Pwinty

Tags: php

I am using Pwinty for a project and I'm trying to update an orders status to Cancelled with the API and the PHP Library [PHPPwinty](http://www.bradpineau.com/PHPPwinty/). (The function for updating order statuses can be found on line 218.)

I have the following code:

```
<?php

    require_once("../config/printer/PHPPwinty.php");

    $pwinty = new PHPPwinty();

    $order = "7733";

    $order_details = $pwinty->getOrder($order);

    print_r($order_details);

    $pwinty->updateOrderStatus($order, "Cancelled");

?>
```

The function in the library looks like the following:

```
/**
* Update the status of an order (to submit or cancel it)
*
* @param string $id Order id
* @param string $status Status to which the order should be updated. Valid values are "Cancelled" or "Submitted"
* @return array The order details
* @access public
*/
function updateOrderStatus($id, $status) {
    $data = array();
    $data["id"] = $id;
    $data["status"] = $status;

    $data = $this->apiCall("/Orders/Status", $data, "POST");
    if (is_array($data)) {
        if (isset($data["error"])) {
            $this->last_error = $data["error"];
            return 0;
        } else {
            return $data;
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Though when I run it I just get the order details and the status is still Submitted. Any suggestions?

Comment: What was the code in Orders/Status page

Comment: If you mean code to update the status, it's the first chunk of code in the question. I have that code and then the library.

Answer (score 1):

with Pwinty, orders can only be cancelled before they are Submitted, so you will find that your call to /Orders/Status is returning a 403 with an error messaging telling you this.

Have you got any way of reading the response status codes and error messages, as these will give you insights into why your calls are not working.

(Reference http://pwinty.com/api)